# CRUDREPOSITRY SAVE METHOD and custom method in same serviceimpl creates javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, persistence, crud-repository

I have Service Impl like below

```
@Transactional
public void addmethod(final requesBOdy requesBOdy)
      throws methodException {
    

    Entityclass entityclassobj =
        repo.findBycol1Andcol2Andcol3Andcol4(col1,col2,col3,col4)
            
    // if above find returns an row already found then update that row as inactive
    if (null != entityclassobj) {
      entityclassobj.setStatusCd(change some value on col4);
      repo.save(entityclassobj;
    }
    // insert the request body into the table
    EntityClass EntityobjForNewRequest =
        new Entityclass();
    setupentity(EntityobjForNewRequest, requestBody);
    repo.save(EntityobjForNewRequest);
}
```

REPO:

```
public interface Repo
    extends CrudRepository<EntityClass, String> {
 
 Entityclass findBycol1Andcol2Andcol3Andcol4(
      String col1, String col2, String col3, String col4);
}
```

problem is, when the request comes from Postman it works well, it finds active row by findBycol1Andcol2Andcol3Andcol4 custom method and update that row as inactive and insert new row from request body. But when we run performance test it triggers two users at same time when user 1 tries to find the active row and it couldn't find one so it inserts the row from request body, at the same time user 2 also tries to find the active row before when user1 commits the row inserted, so it inserted the same row.  Now the third user tries to look up active rows and it was inserted two times earlier it returns list of entities that we are not expected and throwing `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException:` Any leads or pointers would help a lot?

tried this as well JPARepo with saveAndFlush method but no lucj

Comment: So basically it works as it should (preventing duplicates from being inserted). Of course a lookup won't succeed if another transaction hasn't been committed yet (and no `flush` or `saveAndFlush` will change that). You can only read persisted data (that is the whole point of a transaction). If you really want to do this and performance isn't an issue use locking on the database level (pessimistic locking) so that only 1 session can read the data and others have to wait). Or build in a retry mechanism when a constraint violation occurs.

Comment: You can add synchronized keyword for your addmethod function if you are running on a single instance, and the transaction is finalized within this method. Otherwise, you need to use a distributed locking mechanism or a DB based solution...

Comment: @KemalKaplan I Tried synchronized as well but dint help much.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have working examples? This is happening only in our performance test but in real time it will be less traffic one and this scenario is very very rare to happen but interested to fix it before we hit prod